# Static Bool Array Not initializing as set

Tags: c++11, static, initialization, array-initialization

Why are my array of static bools not initialized properly? Only the first one is initialized - I suspect this is because the array is static.

The following MWE was compiled with GCC and is based on a function that I am writing that I have transferred into a main program to illustrate my problem. I have tried with and without c++11. My understanding is because this array is static and initialized to true this should always print the first time I enter my function. So in this MWE it should print once.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int arraysize = 10;
const int myIndex = 1;

static bool firstTimeOverall = true;

int main()
{
    static bool firstCloudForThisClient[arraysize] = {true};
    cout.flush();
    if (firstCloudForThisClient[myIndex])
    {
        cout << "I never get here" << endl;
        firstCloudForThisClient[myIndex] = false;
        if (firstTimeOverall)
        {
            firstTimeOverall = false;
            cout << "But think I would get here if I got in above" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that all the elements of `firstCloudForThisClient` are initialised to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to invert your conditions to take advantage of default initialisation:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int arraysize = 10;
const int myIndex = 1;  // note this index does not access the first element of arrays

static bool firstTimeOverall = true;

int main()
{
    static bool firstCloudForThisClient[arraysize] = {}; // default initialise
    cout.flush();
    if (!firstCloudForThisClient[myIndex])
    {
        cout << "I never get here" << endl;
        firstCloudForThisClient[myIndex] = true; // Mark used indexes with true
        if (firstTimeOverall)
        {
            firstTimeOverall = false;
            cout << "But think I would get here if I got in above" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static bool firstCloudForThisClient[arraysize] = {true};
```

This initializes the first entry to true, and all others to false.

```
if (firstCloudForThisClient[myIndex])
```

However, since `myIndex` is 1 and array indexing is zero-based, this accesses the **second** entry, which is false.

Answer (score 0):

Your are initializing only first element on an array using `array[size] = {true}` , if arraysize variable is bigger then 1, the initial value of other elements depends on platform. I think it is an undefined behavior.

If you really need to init your array, use loop instead:

```
for(int i=0; i < arraysize; ++i)
firstCloudForThisClient[i] = true;
```

Comment: Because this is a static variable for use in a function that is called multiple times I cannot use a loop - does this mean that I should turn this function into an object?

Comment: Yes, it could be usefull to turn this functionality to an object. Or you can move this loop into other function and call it once, for example in the beginning of the program. If you like static varaible so much, you even create a static bool flag, that would protect you of initing array again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I am playinf trying to get some more complicated threading code working with functionality from the point cloud library. For this reason I will take your latter suggestion for now and take your former suggestion (turning it into an object) later. Thank you!

Comment: @GoverNator A list initializer on an array uses the given initializers in order, and value-initializes the rest of the entries, meaning 0 for all primitives (i.e. false for bools). It is not undefined, and not dependent on the platform.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer was useful to me, particularly with the comments added.

EDIT: I see. Thank you for that Sebastian - does this mean I can rely on the other values being zero regardless of platform? If so I will just switch the polarity of my if statements.

Comment: @user3235290 Because the answer is incorrect, as I explained in my comment above.

Comment: @SebastianRedl  Please see my edit above- I was too slow.

Comment: @SebastianRedl thank your for explanation. Now I know more too. But my answer is still a way to avoid situation, when you aren't sure in background initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You should access the first element of the array so use:

```
const int myIndex = 0;
```